# Unable to locate "Filter" icon in amazon mobile app using UIAutomater

Tags: android, selenium, appium, ui-automation

**Scenario** :-

1) I am filtering some poduct by using "Filter" functionality.

2) Then clicking on "Filter" link highlight on yellow colour. I want to minimize this "Filter division" but i'm unable to locate or find any relevant locator for "Filter Link"using **UIAutomater**.

Please refer below screenshot

[image]

I have tried after suggestion but noluck :-

**Error at line 69**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like amazon mobile app is a hybrid app and filter link you are trying to click is available only after switch to WEBVIEW context.

How to check:

Print out result of `driver.getContextHandles()` and see if you have WEBVIEW in the list.

If your element is in WEBVIEW part, then you can [chrome-debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

You should not use `resource-id` as a prefix of `id` for elements in webview: your locator for filter link (if its in webview - must be proved) is invalid

Comment: Hi @dmle i have check getContextHandel able to file [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_chrome, WEBVIEW_stetho_com.jio.media.jiobeats]
[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_chrome, WEBVIEW_stetho_com.jio.media.jiobeats]
[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_chrome, WEBVIEW_stetho_com.jio.media.jiobeats] this list

Comment: i'm not able to see anything in chrome-debugging.